# Why is my NumericUpDown control not honoring its .Minimum property?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a .NET 4 C# WinForms app, I have a few NumericUpDown controls on a particular form. When inputting values at runtime to test, the minimum and maximum values are enforced as expected, except on one control.

I've set the `.Maximum` to 86400 and the `.Minimum` to 3 on the problem control. At runtime, it is only allowing values from ***51*** (!) to 86400.

The designer (auto-generated) code looks like this:

```
this.numEvilControl.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] {
3,
0,
0,
0});
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project, but to no avail.

What's causing this control to come up with its own `.Minimum` value? I don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: I think it's being evil - what's with the decimal construction? You could use `3m` for a `decimal` of value 3.

Comment: The auto generated code looks weird but is a valid way to initialise a decimal to the value 3. There could be a bug anywhere else in your code. You need to post a minimal example that shows the error.

Comment: There's definitely an issue elsewhere. I've just built a WinForms app with a numeric up down with the values you mention, and it's fine. Are you sure the value isn't being set again in OnLoad for example?

Comment: Your generated code works. Can you add more of your code?

Comment: I imagine that you have already executed a global search of `numEvilControl` to check if it is changed somewhere in your code.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis The designer generates the code that way for serialization of some sort. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1526290/161052

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately no... the global search was executed *after* posting the question, in most brilliant fashion. :)

Comment: @JYelton didn't know that - thought you typed this. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than delete the question, I thought I would post how I found the problem...

As it turns out, there was a `.ValueChanged` event which was modifying the value (which I had long forgotten about).

So, to all those who *might* have this problem in the future, check your events before you start wondering why properties are being magically altered!

Comment: :-) As an aside, about 8 years, ago, you would not have been going mad - I recalled this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814347